# Codewars: SyntaxError unexpected token '&&' in a If else statement

Tags: javascript

Trying to solve Opposites Attract kata with an if else statement to check if flower1 has even/odd pedals as well as flower2 using &&.

```
if ((flower1 % 2) == 1) && ((flower2 % 2) == 0){
return true;
```

Which gives a SyntaxError: unexpected token '&&'

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong. There should be one outer set for the `if` and then as many nested sets you need for the expression within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( ((flower1 % 2) == 1) && ((flower2 % 2) == 0) ){
return true;
```

}

You did it correctly just didn't have enough brackets